# how to make a jquery menu that slides and hides what was before?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Basically what i am trying to achieve is having the ul menu on the left side of my content div, at the start only one li should be visible.
Once clicked it has to slide out or a sort of animation and be replaced by 4 **li** that contain the different navigation

```
(function($){
    $(function(){

        $('li.dropdown').click(function() {
            $(this).fadeOut('slow')
                    .siblings('li.stage2').css('display', 'block');
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

this currently does it but the siblings coming in isn't smooth and when the fadOut animation is over they jump in the place of the other, any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
Not a drop down menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly take a look at this code. I built your code fragment and came up with this.

CSS:

```
ul { width: 200px; margin: 20px 0 0 20px; }
li { color: #fff; text-align: center; background-color: #000; border-bottom: 1px dotted #fff; }
li.stage2 { background-color: #0000ff; display: none; }
```

​

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="dropdown">First Stage Menu</li>
    <li class="stage2">Second Stage - 1</li>
    <li class="stage2">Second Stage - 2</li>
    <li class="stage2">Second Stage - 3</li>
    <li class="stage2">Second Stage - 4</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.dropdown').click(function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity:0},1000);
        $(this).siblings('li.stage2').fadeIn(1000);
        $(this).parent().animate({marginTop: '-=20'},1000);
    });​
});
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/P9TQA/1/
Good luck.

Comment: A vote up [if not today, may be next time] would be nice Ms Patsy. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, here is the example how i solved it:

```
$("#menu-balticpoint li").mouseover(function() {

                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var width = $("#"+id+" a").width();
                $("#"+id+" ul li a").css("width", width+"px");
                $("#"+id+" ul").slideDown('fast').show();
        $(this).hover(function() {
        }, function(){
            $("#"+id+" ul").fadeOut('slow').hide().stop(true, true); //When the mouse hovers out of the subnav, move it back up
        });
        });
```

Comment: well thing is as i mentioned it's not a dropdown, the new <li>s will take the place of the first permanently(unless reloaded ofc), picture this:
<li>I want to</li>
<li>buy</li>
<li>Sell</li>
<li>.... 
and so on, when the user lands on the page only the I want to will be visible, once he clicks on it i need it to "dissapear" smoothly and have the other <li>s replace it with a smooth animation as well, let me know if i don't make sense